# Transformar Number em texto binário

Tags: javascript, conversão-de-tipo, números-binários

Como conseguir a representação de um `Number` (inteiro) em binário com JavaScript?

Ex:

```
47 = 00101111
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se quiser que funcione de forma genérica, incluindo negativos:

```js
function dec2bin(dec) {
    return dec >= 0 ? dec.toString(2) : (~dec).toString(2);
}
console.log(dec2bin(47));
console.log(dec2bin(-47));
```

Se quiser fazer um *padding*:

```js
function dec2bin(dec) {
    var binario = dec >= 0 ? dec.toString(2) : (~dec).toString(2);
    var tamanho = binario.length > 32 ? 64 : binario.length > 16 ? 32 : binario.length > 8 ? 16 : 8;
    return ("0".repeat(tamanho) + binario).substr(-tamanho);
}
console.log(dec2bin(47));
console.log(dec2bin(-47));
console.log(dec2bin(12347));
console.log(dec2bin(5612347));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Dec2Bin.js).

Comment: Se encaixou perfeito na minha função. Test.assertEquals rodou de boa =)

Answer (score 6):

Como já foi referido podes usar o [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) e passando como argumento o `2`, que quer dizer base 2, radix 2 ou binário.

Para completar os zeros à esquerda basta mais uma linha de código, algo assim:

```
function binarificar(nr){
    var str = nr.toString(2);
    return '00000000'.slice(str.length) + str;
}

console.log(binarificar(1));  // 00000001
console.log(binarificar(47)); // 00101111
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma opção é essa:

```
(47).toString(2)
```

O método `toString`, em Javascript, aceita em qual base você deseja obter a representação do número inteiro. No caso acima foi na base 2.