# Converter decimal para binário

Tags: javascript, lógica

Estou travado em um problema de logica de programação, onde é preciso criar uma função JavaScript que receba um decimal qualquer e converta para binario.

Comment: Coloque o seu código aqui para que todos possam ver e poder ajudar.

Comment: Não seria fácil usar o que tem pronto? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134455/101

Comment: Seja bem-vindo Pedro Castro, para obter exito nas suas perguntas leia esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEC2BIN` converte um número decimal em um número binário

```js
function dec2bin(dec){
    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}


console.log(dec2bin(256));

console.log(dec2bin(1024));
```

```
 Resultado  Formula 
 1010       = DEC2BIN(10)   
 01010      = DEC2BIN(10, 5)    
 1111100000 = DEC2BIN(-32)
```

> [**Se quiser fazer um padding ou ver outras opções clique aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163246/transformar-number-em-texto-bin%C3%A1rio/163252#163252)

[**Fonte e mais opções**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939760/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-binary-in-javascript)

Comment: demais! obrigado